# busybox brctl : Package not installed

Tags: android, cross-compiling, busybox

There is a program that needs bridge-utils.

But 
I cross-compiled the program for Android.(default for linux)

I should use the brctl command.

But I can not install bridge-utils on Android.
So I tried to use the brctl command with busybox.

```
$ busybox brctl addbr
BusyBox v1.21.1 (2015-02-16 16:54:27 KST) multi-call binary.

Usage: brctl COMMAND [BRIDGE [INTERFACE]]

Manage ethernet bridges

Commands:
        show                    Show a list of bridges
        addbr BRIDGE            Create BRIDGE
        delbr BRIDGE            Delete BRIDGE
        addif BRIDGE IFACE      Add IFACE to BRIDGE
        delif BRIDGE IFACE      Delete IFACE from BRIDGE
        setageing BRIDGE TIME           Set ageing time
        setfd BRIDGE TIME               Set bridge forward delay
        sethello BRIDGE TIME            Set hello time
        setmaxage BRIDGE TIME           Set max message age
        setpathcost BRIDGE COST         Set path cost
        setportprio BRIDGE PRIO         Set port priority
        setbridgeprio BRIDGE PRIO       Set bridge priority
        stp BRIDGE [1/yes/on|0/no/off]  STP on/off
```

And

```
$ busybox brctl addbr brlan
brctl: bridge brlan : Package not installed
```

Do I need additional files? or cross-compiled bridge-utils?

Thank you! Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified kernel options and rebuild
It's answer

Need bridging option in kernel

use # make ARCH=arm menuconfig